# Constraints unbounded for FittedBox inside Expanded inside container with width

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make this:

```
[Buy                $5,99"]
```

For that, I divided the row in 2 using `flex`. The first piece for `Buy` and the second for `$5,99`, which I align to the right obviously.

However, I cannot make it work. I tried `FittedBox` but also other things. I get

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
```

Which makes no sense since the expanded is inside a container with defined `width`.

```
     Expanded(
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(ROUNDNESSS),
                  bottomRight: const Radius.circular(ROUNDNESSS),
                ),
              ),
              child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                          child: Text("Buy",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              )),
                          flex: 1),
                      Flexible(
                          child: Text("\$5,99",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              )),
                          flex: 1)
                    ],
                  ))),
          flex: 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not expand Text widgets.  Containers can be expanded so wrapping each of your text widgets in a Container is a start.  Now, the containers will not change their dimensions unless they are Expanded. Now inside Expanded you have a property called flex that will work.  Here is some working code.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.cyan,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text("\$5,99",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("Buy",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  )),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

This, however does not give you the look you were going for. To achieve the spacing you were aiming for there is a much simpler solution using the mainAxisAlignment property of the Row

```
child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```